# Multiple channels on Hyperledger Fabric - IBM Bluemix starter plan

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

I'm using "`composer-cli`" and attempting to test below described  scenario using the composer. I use IBM blockchain starter plan.

I have 3 members(Comapny A, Company B and CompanyC). My Requirement is to create two seperate channels (  1) "pasnbank"  which is between Company A and Company B and 2) "vehiclelife" between Company B and CompanyC ) and install bsuiness netwroks "pasanbank-network.bna" and "vehicle-lifecycle-network.bna" in to respective channels. Is this scenario supported on the starter paln? if so please provide the instructions. Currently I use [this link](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/develop_starter.html#deploying-a-business-network) as the reference. It doesn't have instructions on how to specify specific channel when installing the business network.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create multiple channels and deploy your separate business networks there - you can create the channels from the network monitor dashboard. You will need to define the appropriate business network cards with the correct connection profiles to connect to your business network(s) - see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/connectionprofile

This tutorial should help -> https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-deploy-blockchain-starter-plan-network/index.html

See also 
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/howto/create_channel.html#creating-or-updating-a-channel

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/get_start_starter_plan.html#getting-started-with-starter-plan

You can refer to the Composer docs  https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials or contact IBM support about specific issues you have to get the business network(s) deployed to your Starter plan instance.